# How can I use "text-decoration" within <span> in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to use `text-decoration` to underline a word in a heading but I can't figure out how to do it in CSS. Is it even possible?
I thought about using `<span>` but is there a way to use multiple spans and address them separately in CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to do it using CSS, you can assign an id to the span element. Then use CSS to style it

```
<span id="under">Hello</span>
```

And the CSS

```
#under{
    text-decoration : underline;
}
```

And if you want to underline multiple spans, you can use class attribute.

```
<span class="under"> </span>

.under{
text-decoration : underline;
}
```

Comment: better use `class` instead of `id` ;)

Answer (score 0):

For underlined text in HTML, use [the `<u>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_u.asp).

Comment: I thought about that too, but what is more common? <u> is more easy for sure.

Comment: Unless you want to mark a misspelled word or a proper name when writing Chinese, `<u>` is definitely not the right way to underline a word.

Comment: What do you mean by misspelled word? You mean like on an educational website? You would also rather you spans for text-decoration?

Comment: @Hip read this documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u

Comment: Does this also apply when I want to use "overline" or "line-through"? How would I do this then? Because <u> is not right in this case or am I wrong?